# how to add a sign like dollar to the end of input value of Gravity Forms entry after submition

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I need an input type for percentage input which will add the % sign at the end of the user input and also an input type for currency without the text of currency(CAD, USD, ...). I just need a $ sign
and I also use a PDF maker for gravity forms that I need the Correct Values to be printed in both pdf and email with sign

I tried gform_after_create_post_39 and gform_pre_submission_39 which 39 is the id of the form
This is the code :

```
add_action( 'gform_after_submission_39', 'pre_submission_handler' );
function pre_submission_handler( $form ) {
    if(isset($_POST['input_16']) && !empty($_POST['input_16'])) {
            $_POST['input_16'] = $_POST['input_16'] . ' %';
            
            
    }
    if(isset($_POST['input_17']) && !empty($_POST['input_17'])) {
            $_POST['input_17'] = $_POST['input_17'] . ' $';
    }
}
```

I need to add % sign at the end of input_16 value in email and PDF
and also I need to add $ sign to the end of input_17's value in the email and PDF

i tried to echo $_POST['input_16'] or $_POST['input_17'] the output is correct but it is not effected in email and PDF

Comment: [Please don't add **SOLVED** to the title of your question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116101). If it has been solved by an answer, you can accept that answer, if you solved the problem yourself you [write your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and accept that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. here is the Answer :

I added a simple Text input to the form and then by using this code
I can change the specific input value or update it by adding the sign at the end of an entry before notification send
'gform_pre_submission_39' -> 39 is the ID of the form that I want to change its input value
'input_130' -> is the simple text input with id 130 that I need to add % to the end

This hook will perform before Notification and after Form Validation!
So the changes will apply on PDF and email!
in the beginning, the problem was from the input which was number format so when I added % or $ sign to the end of the entry after the form submission it didn't accept because it was number format.
sorry for my English, I hope I could help someone who has such a problem in the future

```
add_action( 'gform_pre_submission_39', 'pre_submission_handler' );
function pre_submission_handler( $form ) {
    // INPUT 130 - Basic Coverage
    if(isset($_POST['input_130']) && !empty($_POST['input_130'])) {
        if(strpos($_POST['input_130'], '%') == false) {
            $_POST['input_130'] = $_POST['input_130'] . '%';
        } else {
            //Do Nothing
        }
    }
    if(isset($_POST['input_131']) && !empty($_POST['input_131'])) {
        if (strpos($_POST['input_130'], '$') == false) {
            $_POST['input_131'] = $_POST['input_131'] . '$';
        } else {
            //Do Nothing
        }
    }

}
```